# How to gain access to local files using remote desktop in java (or) How to open a folder in local pc using remote desktop server in java?

Tags: java, jsp, psexec

I created one java project on remote desktop server. I opened that project on local pc through remote desktop server. When i click link, i want open folder in local pc.

Comment: Please do not tag javascript if you are explictly asking about Java. I also doubt JSP is related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's not directly possible by remote desktop but you can add you PC over a VPN or web server as a network drive on your remote desktop server.

Comment: How to open local folder on my laptop using another localhost server. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use "VPNs" like hamachi or tunngle. Install one of these programms or an alternative on both the local pc and the remote server and join the same private network. After that you can gain network access to some folders on you private local pc. On the remote server you can add a new network drive over the hamachi or tunngle ipv4 adress of the local pc to gain access to the "network available" folder on you local pc.